# Grep for a text in three log files

Tags: linux, grep

i have a text to be grepped which can update in any of the 3 log files suppose

> a1.log  a2.log a3.log

i have used the below command to get the text from 3 files but the response is as below

```
cd /path to the files;grep " XXXXX token" | a *.log | cut -d "=" -f6
grep: a: No such file or directory
The test i am searching
```

I am getting response but i dont want the 1st line (grep: a: No such file or directory) in my response. Any help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you given the exact command you tried? I think the `|` in `grep " XXXXX token" | a *.log` is a mistake... the error you get is because of the space between `a` and `*.log`, should have been `a*.log` or `a[1-3].log`

Comment: you have a typo. it should be ```grep " XXXXX token" a*.log```

Comment: also, you could use `awk -F'=' '/XXXXX token/{print $6}' a[1-3].log` instead of `grep + cut` combo

Comment: `grep " XXXXX token" a[123].log | cut -d "=" -f6` would make a lot more sense...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for to extract the line(s) specifically is

```
$ grep " XXXXX token" *.log
```

...which will get every line matching the search from every ".log"-file in the current directory.